# Formatting output of a list in Python

Tags: python, curses

I have a Python script that prints a set of nodes from a list on a unix console by category like so

```
   
node_name: 1) node_mgt  2) node103  3) node106  4) node107  5) node109  6) node110  7)     node115  8) node116  9) node117  10) node120  11) node121  12) node122  
node_sub1: 170) node126  171) node210  172) node304  173) node413  174) node425  175)     node517  176) node609
```

How can I format the output where the nodes are aligned regardless of console size? such as

```
node_name: 1) node_mgt  2) node103  3) node106  4) node107  5) node109  6) node110 
           7) node115  8) node116  9) node117  10) node120  11) node121  12) node122        
node_sub1: 170) node126  171) node210  172) node304  173) node413  174) node425 
           175) node517  176) node609
```

Comment: Is this really a Python question. It seems to me more like a console GUI question, i.e. how does your script find out the current console width? That depends on OS, tty/ptty, termcap/terminfo/curses etc. and may be an unanswerable question. Of course you could just have a -w option so that -w80 tells it to act as if console width is 80 chars.

Comment: Console width determined with curses.tigetnum('cols') on all the Linux nodes at work.

Comment: You didn't mention curses in your question so I added the curses tag.

Answer (score 4):

Hanging indents are possible using the [textwrap module](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap):

```
import textwrap

lines=['node_name: 1) node_mgt  2) node103  3) node106  4) node107  5) node109  6) node110  7) node115  8) node116  9) node117  10) node120  11) node121  12) node122  ',
'node_sub1: 170) node126  171) node210  172) node304  173) node413  174) node425  175) node517  176) node609']
for line in lines:
    print(textwrap.fill(line,initial_indent='',subsequent_indent=' '*11,width=84))
```

yields

```
node_name: 1) node_mgt  2) node103  3) node106  4) node107  5) node109  6) node110
           7) node115  8) node116  9) node117  10) node120  11) node121  12) node122
node_sub1: 170) node126  171) node210  172) node304  173) node413  174) node425
           175) node517  176) node609
```

Comment: ah great.. I will implement with textwrap

Answer (score 1):

[pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) is what you're looking for.

A more complex example:
[pretty-print-lists-in-python](http://www.mindtwist.de/main/linux/3-linux-tipps/48-how-to-pretty-print-lists-in-python.html)